# Installing nagios 4.0.8 on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, server, monitoring, nagios3

I am trying to install and setup Nagios 4.0.8 on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS server. What is the ideal way to do this ? The official Ubuntu documentation regarding nagios installation is related to nagios version 3.x and is available [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/nagios.html). However, I want to install the latest stable release which is nagios 4.0.8. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Open your terminal and type these commands and run these commands as root user

```
sudo apt-get install wget build-essential apache2 php5-gd libgd2-xpm libgd2-xpm-dev libapache2-mod-php5

wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/nagios/nagios-4.0.8.tar.gz

useradd nagios
groupadd nagcmd
usermod -a -G nagcmd nagios

./configure --with-nagios-group=nagios --with-command-group=nagcmd -–with-mail=/usr/bin/sendmail

make all
make install
make install-init
make install-config
make install-commandmode
make install-webconf
cp -R contrib/eventhandlers/ /usr/local/nagios/libexec/
chown -R nagios:nagios /usr/local/nagios/libexec/eventhandlers
/usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios -v /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg
/etc/init.d/nagios start

htpasswd –c /usr/local/nagios/etc/htpasswd.users nagiosadmin

cd /tmp/nagios-plugins-2.0
./configure --with-nagios-user=nagios --with-nagios-group=nagios
make
make install 

ln -s /etc/init.d/nagios /etc/rcS.d/S99nagios
```

and finally open this link in your browser

```
http://<your.nagios.server.ip>/nagios
```

Note: If you just google , you can find this document very easily

http://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/Installing_Nagios_Core_From_Source.pdf

I thought I have helped you enough.

Let me know if any issue.

Jai Hind.

Comment: I did come across this guide. But on Ubuntu 14.04, I ran into a few issues while trying to follow the given steps. I was able to get it up and running after referring http://sharadchhetri.com/2014/08/25/install-nagios-4-source-ubuntu-14-04-lts/ and http://www.sysads.co.uk/2014/08/install-nagios-core-4-0-8-ubuntu-14-04/ in addition to the link you have mentioned.

Comment: ok @JayakrishnanGK glad u got it.